# jquery multi-level animated drop down contained within div and animated on change

Tags: jquery, navigation, jquery-animate, css-position, drop-down-menu

I'm in need of help refining a jquery drop down navbar.

The navigation can have multiple levels, and at any point there can be a "detail" pane that appears to the right of the currently hovered item.

It's not easy to explain in words so I have set up the following http://jsfiddle.net/S8tyW/

I need to kill the bugs which appear when moving from different levels repeatedly or quickly.

There are also times when the animation triggers when it's not needed to.. i.e. when you hover over different items with "detail" panes.

I've looked about for useful guides but it's got to the point where I need someone else to look at it with fresh eyes.

I really hope someone can help as I have a lot of use for these kind of drop downs and I'm sure this could be turned into a very useful plugin.

Any feedback would be very much appreciated!

Kind Regards,

Dan

Comment: I checked your jsfiddle example with Firefox 11 and it's hard to tell if anything is wrong with your menu. It looks fine to me. Explain what the bugs are exactly and which browser you are using to test.

Comment: Thanks for looking. the issues occur when going "main party > with children > more children > final with detail" and then going back up to "main party > with children > final with detail" the height is not reduced back correctly after viewing a "detail" pane.

Comment: Also, ideally each child would be resized to the tallest currently displayed list, as the going from the bottom option in "main party" to it's child nav wouldn't trigger the navigation collapse if you don't make it over the child quickly enough (try leaving your mouse over the yellow container div)

Comment: So basically you always need to keep track of the tallest menu that's currently visible. If each child is resized to the tallest currently displayed list, what if the child is actually the currently tallest list? Do you want it's parents to be resized as well?

Comment: @TJ resizing the parents shouldn't be necessary (from an interaction point of view). that would require keeping track of the original height of each ul in order to shrink it back down to fit if the user goes back a level or two. as long as it always fits the contents and it's not going to hide the nav unexpectedly. as you can probably tell from my code I'm no JS expert, hence why I'm having trouble neatening this up and making it production-ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have re-written this and it's reliable enough now for me to use... I have updated the fiddle in the question with the working code in case anyone want's to utilize this.

There's still occasionally some odd behavior but it's only when stress testing and rapidly moving from one to the next then back up multiple levels.